# how to embed flash games into Windows Forms application.net compact framework under windows mobile 6

Tags: windows, flash, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I want develop an application on windows mobile.
In this app, i need to show some Flash games to the end user.

1. How should I do?

   - embed an `Flash ActiveX Control` (in Windows mobile Form application) ?
   - embed an `IE control`?
2. BTW (because i do not have a windows mobile device now)
   Can I views flash in IE of the windows mobile device?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT1**:
 This link talks about how to  [Hosting ActiveX Controls in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx)
 This article helped me.

for play flash, [Macromedia Flash Player 7 for Pocket PC](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer_pocketpc/downloads/player.html) should be installed on your windows mobile emulator.

**EDIT2**:
  after practice i found following package should be installed before your windows mobile programming:

- Vista SP2
- Visual Studio 2008 SP1
- Windows Mobile Device Center

**EDIT3**:
  and I found the this helpful link talks about [Interaction Between a Flash Movie and the Database through the Hosting C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/FlashDBInteract.aspx)

**EDIT4**:
  and this link for [Enable Network Connection Windows Mobile 6 Emulator](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Enable-Network-Connection-Windows-Mobile-6-Emulator.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On WinMo you currently only get Flash Lite and the old Player version 7. General-purpose desktop Flash games will probably not run. Adobe are promising full Flash for mobile operating systems with the 10.1 release; maybe that'll work for you when it comes out.

I'd definitely try to embed Flash rather than a web browser control, as IE Mobile is a hive of bugs and differences between OS versions. Keep IE Mobile out of the equation as much as possible if you value your sanity. It remains to be seen how embedding Flash will work in the new Player. But it's worth getting the VirtualPC images for Windows Mobile set up now to play and test with.

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible.  See:

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer_pocketpc/

or Google

```
flash internet explorer windows mobile
```

You can (maybe) just view the Flash in IE, or you could place a WebBrowser control on a form (in .Net) and view it there.